# Discord API returning error 50006 : Cannot send an empty message

Tags: json, discord, postman, webhooks, insomnia

I'd like to send multiple messages using webhooks and JSON but the Discord API is returning an error 50006 "Cannot send an empty message".

My header mentions that the content type is JSON and here's my code :

```
{"messages":{

    "message1": [

        {   "username": "Dino",
            "content": "Test1"
        }
    ],
    "message2": [
        {"username": "Dino",
            "content": "Test2"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Discord's API is not smart enough to do this, read some documentations of the Discord's API on the official page